# Best resources to learn SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am looking for the best resources to learn SharePoint Online development (apart from MSDN).
There are lot of good books, articles on SharePoint Server, but very few on SharePoint Online.
Can somebody point me in right direction?

Answer (score 2):

how about this to get you going:

- [Office 365 for the IT Pro - Lync Online, SharePoint Online & Deployment](https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/office-365-for-the-it-pro-lync-online-sharePoint-online-Deployment?ocid=otc-f-corp-jtc-DPU-MVA_O365LyncSPDeploy)
- [Using SharePoint Online for Enterprises](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/hh397890.aspx)
- [SharePoint Online: software boundaries and limits](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/sharepoint-online-software-boundaries-and-limits-HA102694293.aspx?CTT=1)
- [SharePoint Online Planning Guide for Office 365 Enterprise and Midsize](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/sharepoint-online-planning-guide-for-office-365-enterprise-and-midsize-HA101988931.aspx?CTT=1)
- [Introduction to the SharePoint Online Management Shell](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/introduction-to-the-sharepoint-online-management-shell-HA102915057.aspx?CTT=1)
- [a search ;) with many links white papers vids](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=Sharepoint%20online&ac=4)
- [many many vids for sharepoint online](http://www.daveduggan.com/category/cloud/office365/sharepoint-online/)

The SharePoint sweet is pritty much the same, only some things done slightly differently eg using the interface! programming wise its pritty much the same stuff! msdn is your friend ;)

Comment: btw, the last link doesn't work goes to a go-daddy parking page.

Comment: try http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?hl=en-GB&biw=&bih=&q=cache:dlClMfEqrwYJ:http://www.daveduggan.com/category/cloud/office365/sharepoint-online/%2Bhttp://www.daveduggan.com/category/cloud/office365/sharepoint-online/&gbv=2&ct=clnk

Answer (score 0):

Lynda is the  best training website available out there on the web share point and host of other softwares. I started using it a few weeks ago and I can't help to express my excitement about what it offers.
It is an all-in-one website that can satisfy your appetite to learn virtually any skills. It has a collection of staggering 2400 + tutorials by world famous experts in the areas of software’s, photography, design, business skills, animation, audio, CAD, developer, education, photography, video, web and many more.
I had tried many paid and free training websites in the past but none offers such a comprehensive range of courses. The courses are carefully and elegantly designed to make it easy for even beginners to learn a new skills.

Only con is that it is a paid service. But after using it for more than a month I feel it is worth my hard earned money. 
Explore Lynda website:

http://www.lynda.com/?utm_medium=ldc-partner&utm_source=SSPRC&utm_content=10919&utm_campaign=CD15925&bid=10919&aid=CD15925
Free trial: I came to know that Lynda is now offering a limited time 7 day free trial for new members. Visit and register through this link for a free trial :

http://www.lynda.com/promo/trial/Default.aspx?lpk35=1833&utm_medium=ldc-partner&utm_source=SSPRC&utm_content=655&utm_campaign=CD15925&bid=655&aid=CD15925

It is entirely free, but they will charge your credit card with $1 during registration and then refund it. I came to know from my friends that it’s to limit the number of free registrations.